# Need suggestion in query builder of Laravel 9 application

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

How to avoid foreach-loop because Laravel query builder is used to get a single record detail.
When I tried without foreach-loop, the following error occurred "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance".

**Controller**

```
public function show(Student $student)
    {
        $result = DB::table('students')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('id', "=" ,$student['id'])
        ->get();

        foreach($result as $studentData){} 
        return view('student.show', ['studentData' => $studentData]);
    }
```

**Blade View**

```
{{ $studentData->name}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->get()` always returns a Collection, even if there's only one match. If you only want the first record, you can use `->first()` instead.

Comment: In other words, ->get() use for multiple records and  ->first() use for single record.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have to use raw queries? I assume Student is a Laravel Model, in that case, you should be able to use `Student::find($id)` to get the model directly.